# Gtk treeview to fit contents

Tags: gtk

I have such GUI situation:

Window1>vbox1>vbox2>scrolledvindow1>treeview1>treestore1.

Program takes data from database through MySql C-api. Depending on query here may be data for 0 rows up to over thousand to show in treeview1. By constructing GUI in glade i set 'width request' for window1 and 'height request' for treeview1 to be able to see data in rows.

Is it possible to make that my window1 (or vbox2) automatically resizes for amount of data in treeview1 to avoid blank window on screen when I have only row or two.
I mean that window should be able 'hold' 1-24 rows with resizing and after 24-th row scrollbars should come to treeview1.

Is this possible to do in C language and how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can't size [gtktreeview](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTreeView.html) based on contents, but you can probably use [gtk-widget-set-size-request](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-size-request) to do it on your own.